# Static IP from other región GCP

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have an instance in southamerica-b region in Google Cloud Platform because I want low ping. When I reserved an static ip in southamerica-b region assigned me one ip from USA. I was specting like 80 ms, not 180 ms. Can anyone explain me what's happening?

```
C:\Users\PabloGod>tracert 35.198.37.20

Traza a la dirección 20.37.198.35.bc.googleusercontent.com [35.198.37.20]
sobre un máximo de 30 saltos:

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.1.1
  2     9 ms     9 ms     9 ms  192.168.33.16
  3    15 ms    18 ms    16 ms  10.112.72.13
  4     *        *        *     Tiempo de espera agotado para esta solicitud.
  5    15 ms    14 ms    15 ms  10.111.2.77
  6    14 ms    15 ms    13 ms  176.52.252.248
  7    79 ms    81 ms    98 ms  213.140.43.158
  8    76 ms    75 ms    76 ms  google-ae15-0-grtmiabr4.net.telefonicaglobalsolutions.com [216.184.112.171]
  9    84 ms    77 ms    76 ms  108.170.253.18
 10    76 ms    76 ms    76 ms  108.170.231.84
 11   182 ms   182 ms   183 ms  64.233.174.132
 12   183 ms   183 ms   182 ms  108.170.245.129
 13   182 ms   182 ms   182 ms  66.249.94.21
 14     *        *        *     Tiempo de espera agotado para esta solicitud.
 15     *        *        *     Tiempo de espera agotado para esta solicitud.
```

Comment: Can you include a traceroute to the IP address, so we can see the actual  path that is taking 180ms? geo-location APIs aren't very accurate so you might not actually have a "US" IP address.

Comment: Google Compute Engine VM instances can only be assigned a regional static IP. You were not assigned an IP address in the United States. The IP address is located in the same region as your instance. However, that does not explain the long tracert times once you hit Google's netblock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have two things to take into account.

On one hand, the IPs thing. As John said, you can't trust geolocation as most of Google IPs are registered in the US, they appear there when you try to locate them. Also as he said:

> "Google Compute Engine VM instances can only be assigned a regional static IP. You were not assigned an IP address in the United States. The IP address is located in the same region as your instance."

On the other hand, you have to bear in mind Google recommendations regarding latency estimations. You can find them [here](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/best-practices-compute-engine-region-selection#measure_user_latency). Basically, what it says is that you can estimate 1 ms of round-trip latency for every 100 km traveled. Which means in this case ~8400 km (Distance from Spain, according the IP, to Brasil) * 2 = 16800 km, which devided by 100 is an approx of 168 ms. Indeed if you multiply it by 1.5 as Google suggests, you have 252 ms estimation, so this leaves the latency you got as pretty logic and reasonable.

Also, [here](https://cloud.google.com/about/locations/#network-tab) you can find Google network's map, in order to figure out how your data is traveling around.

Finally, you can use [this tool](http://www.gcping.com/) to estimate the latency from your location to the different zones.